# How can I select a value matching my input from a TypeAhead control using WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

So ordinarily the element I want to pick from a list would be populated on a page and I'd just find it and pick it.  But I'm dealing with a control that doesn't populate list elements until some input has been stuck into a text box, after which it gives me a list of recommendations.

For an example of the kind of list I'm talking about think of Facebook's "People, Places, and Things" search field.

I want to plug a string into this text box, select the same string from the list of recommendations, and submit the form.  The issue I'm having right now is I can't seem to get Mechanize to even recognize the field is there.  I examine a dump of `$mech->find_all_inputs` and it isn't listed.  Is this kind of field just beyond Mechanize's jurisdiction?

Comment: WWW::Mechanize::Firefox is probably the solution to your problem, since this is a Javascript issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This control's magic comes via Javascript, and (as you know) **WWW::Mechanize don't work with Javascript**.

But you can find (with Firefox's HTTPFox extension for example) what request your browser sends to the target site than you get "recommendations" and *make the same request (I'm sure this is POST) from your WWW::Mechanize object*.

Comment: Yup, you get to be the JavaScript interpreter for a little while. If web scraping was easy, everybody would want to do it. ;-)